# What is the difference between DS reference scope "prototype" and "prototype_required"?

Tags: eclipse, osgi, apache-felix, declarative-services

What is the difference between the two of them, as stated in the title ? The end result is the component references to services that uses the prototype service scope, isn't it ?

Comment: "Every component instance in a bundle **may** (PROTOTYPE) vs. **must** (PROTOTYPE_REQUIRED) use a distinct service object.": https://vogella.com/blog/control-osgi-ds-component-instances/ /cc @DirkFauth